# Example of completely positive map from Mn to Mm

Tags: functional-analysis

I can't find any example could someone please show me one because I am trying to understand completely positive maps

Comment: The identity map is completely positive. So is multiplication by $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n>m$, you can compress: $A\longmapsto PAP$, where $PAP$ is the $m\times m$ "upper left corner" of $A$.

If $n\leq m$, you can embed:
$$
A\longmapsto\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Of course these are just the trivial maps there could be many others.